# Web API CORS support not working on http

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cors

I have enabled CORS support on my Web API controller and it works fine on https, but on http I'm still getting this *o 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource* error.

In WebApiConfig I have enabled cors by using this line:

```
// Allow cross site javascript calls
config.EnableCors();
```

And my controller class is introduced like this:

```
 [EnableCors("*","*","*")]
 public class ExternalDataController : ApiController
```

So how I can enable CORS on http and https?

On azure raw http logs following lines appear when I create a one call:

```
2015-05-06 05:53:15 ~1PROJECTX GET /diagnostics/settings X-ARR-LOG-ID=d5d487c0-8d32-4103-98cb-37fd7b022942 443 - 137.116.210.73 Portal-Exp/5.11.2.704+(Websites)+Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML%2C+like+Gecko)+Chrome/42.0.2311.90+Safari/537.36+OPR/29.0.1795.47 - - projectx-development.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 733 1215 3921
2015-05-06 05:53:20 ~1PROJECTX POST /diagnostics/settings X-ARR-LOG-ID=599cb771-d399-49ee-89a2-6804af7c2712 443 - 137.116.210.73 Portal-Exp/5.11.2.704+(Websites)+Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML%2C+like+Gecko)+Chrome/42.0.2311.90+Safari/537.36+OPR/29.0.1795.47 ARRAffinity=a32808ec0f09a64a5ce1705808bf8a2fb0c447c78db8498153641c9469a96a96 - projectx-development.scm.azurewebsites.net 204 0 0 500 1497 156
2015-05-06 05:53:21 ~1PROJECTX GET /diagnostics/settings X-ARR-LOG-ID=6d7bcfd4-aeeb-4c02-9f02-cf5bd54d2189 443 - 137.116.210.73 Portal-Exp/5.11.2.704+(Websites)+Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML%2C+like+Gecko)+Chrome/42.0.2311.90+Safari/537.36+OPR/29.0.1795.47 ARRAffinity=a32808ec0f09a64a5ce1705808bf8a2fb0c447c78db8498153641c9469a96a96 - projectx-development.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 732 1301 78
```

Comment: Please post http RAW headers for client request and response . You may use fiddler to get these details. 

In addition, you also want to check if the METHOD type is allowed at config level. I have seen that DELETE is not allowed by default and it create this problem as well.

Comment: I'm testing the software from jsfiddle with following call:
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://projectx-development.azurewebsites.net/Api/ExternalData/Test"
        }).done(function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }).error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            
        });

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html

Comment: In web.config I have redirect from http to https... I think that is causing problems.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use OWIN? Just enable CORS in your `Configuration` method:

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        #region CORS

        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll); 

        #endregion
```

Comment: Actually I'm having ASP.NET MVC with Owin and Web API controller in a same project. I tried that app.usecors, but still no improvement. I had to remove config.enablecors because it raised error about multiple x-origin headers

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I have not checked at Controller level.

I have the following at WebApi config level and it is working as expected.

```
 var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*") ;
            config.EnableCors(cors);
```

Similarly if you are using Basic auth then make sure that you set SupportsCredentials value  as well

```
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*") { SupportsCredentials = true };
```